# Java Fx bind array of IntegerProperties to multiple columns

Tags: javafx, tableview

Results

```
public class Results {
    
    
    //Variables
    private final StringProperty id;
    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty name;
    ... 
    private final IntegerProperty[] points;
    
    ...
    ...
    
    public StringProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
    
    
    public IntegerProperty[] getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty propertyAt (int index) {
        return points [index];
    }
}
```

However I can’t figure out how to do the same with the IntegerPropertiy[]

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<Results> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Results, String> idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Results, String> nameColumn;
    ...

    ...
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
```

The table looks like this at the moment:
Points[0] is supposed to be Points 1 and so forth
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgfaX.png)

So basically the question is if there is a way I can use the IntegerProperty[] points in a similar way to the other properties and if someone could explain it to me in a simple manner.

Comment: [mcve] please, demonstrating what you are after and what doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are defined in FXML:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Results, Number> pointsColumn1 ;

// etc...

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // ...

    pointsColumn1.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().propertyAt(0));
    // etc....
}
```

Of course it's probably easier to create those columns in Java, rather than in FXML:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {

    int numPoints = 8 ; 
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= numPoints ; i++) {
        TableColumn<Results, Number> column = new TableColumn<>("Points "+i);
        final int index = i - 1 ;
        column.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().propertyAt(index));
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    // ...
}
```